# how to use test data from excel file with page object model in java appium

Tags: java, pageobjects

I wanted to use testdata from excel file with page object model here is the code:
`TestData.java`

```
public class TestData {

    public void testData() throws Exception {
        
        String filePath = "C:\\eclipes\\testdata\\testdata.xlsx";
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        
        //get cell data
        XSSFCell data1 = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(1).getCell(0); //A2  
        XSSFCell data2 = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(2).getCell(0); //B2
```

in my `Test.java` file

```
public class TestSample extends BaseClass {
    
    @Test
    public void tc_01() throws Exception {
    
    String excelData1 = TestData.data1;
    }
```

Am I missing something?
TestData class does not return the data1 value.
or should I need to initialize data1 and 2 in TestData class?

Comment: `data1` and `data2` are local variables inside the `testData` method.  `TestData.data1`  refers to a static member of class `TestData`.  These are two completely different things.